# what is __ char in a char array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am reviewing a code (here is the class: https://github.com/ekscrypto/Base32/blob/master/Base32/MF_Base32Additions.m ) and this code includes below array. I am wondering what is this. because the code is working right but the `__` char ?

```
static char decodingTable[256] = {
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x00 - 0x0F
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x10 - 0x1F
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x20 - 0x2F
            __,__,26,27, 28,29,30,31, __,__,__,__, __, 0,__,__,  // 0x30 - 0x3F
            __, 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9,10, 11,12,13,14,  // 0x40 - 0x4F
            15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,22, 23,24,25,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x50 - 0x5F
            __, 0, 1, 2,  3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9,10, 11,12,13,14,  // 0x60 - 0x6F
            15,16,17,18, 19,20,21,22, 23,24,25,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x70 - 0x7F
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x80 - 0x8F
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0x90 - 0x9F
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xA0 - 0xAF
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xB0 - 0xBF
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xC0 - 0xCF
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xD0 - 0xDF
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xE0 - 0xEF
            __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__, __,__,__,__,  // 0xF0 - 0xFF
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see at the [line above](https://github.com/ekscrypto/Base32/blob/master/Base32/MF_Base32Additions.m#L20):

```
#define __ 255
```

So, `__` in that file is defined as 255.